# Examining the convergence with parameter $a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $a \in R$, let $x_1=a$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(x_{n}^2+3)$ for all  $n≥2$. Examine the convergence of the sequence ${x_n}$ for different values of $a$. Also, find $\lim x_n$, whenever it exists.

I am having problems on how to take $a$ as a parameter. I am unable to think which all values of $a$ would give different results.
Hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: To begin with you can consider the cases $a=1, a<1$ and $a>1$

Comment: If you aren't able to find the limit if it exists, you don't have to think about $a$ at all. If you can find that limit, you should tell us how, so we know how you're doing math, and which explanations you may or may not understand.

Comment: @Naive, I am still having issues why the value of $a$ should affect the answer...

Comment: If you look closely the entire sequence is defined in terms of $a$. As $a$ changes so does your sequence. Just check what sequences you get for $a=1$ and $a=2$. Are both the sequences same?

Comment: You're having issues with starting to work. Why don't you just do a few iterations with different starting values $a$? Make sure you have values both bigger and smaller than 3 in your sample.

Comment: Take a = 1. Is the sequence increase? Take a > 1, is the sequence increase? Take a < 1, is the sequence decreasing?

Comment: @Naive, ok. I got it. For both $a<>1$, the sequence is diverging? Only for $a=1$, I will get a limit. How do I write a formal proof?

Comment: How did you come to such a dangerous conclusion?

Comment: @Naive I am sorry. I hurriedly wrote diverging. For $a<1$ too, I think it is approaching $1$

Comment: You can't give a formal proof of a wrong statement: it doesn't always converge, that depends (surprise!) on $a$. Start working, finally!

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$ converge to a limit $x$ then it must satisfy the definition $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}(x_{n}^2+3)$, that is $x=\frac{1}{4}(x^2+3)$ which gives two values $x=1;\;x=3$.

If $|a|<3$ I see that $x_n\to 1$

if $|a|=3$ then $x_n\to 3$

if $|a|>3$ then $x_n\to \infty$

You have to prove the details

Hope this helps a little

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $a>3$.

Hence, $$x_{n+1}-3=\frac{(x_n-3)(x_n+3)}{4}>0$$ and by induction we obtain here $x_n>3$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

In another hand, $$x_{n+1}-3=\frac{(x_{n-1}-3)(x_{n-1}+3)}{4}>$$
$$>\frac{3}{2}(x_{n-1}-3)>\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2(x_{n-2}-3)>...>\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}(x_1-3),$$
which says that for $a>3$ our sequence does not converge.

2. $a=3$.

In this case $x_n=3$ and our sequence converges.

3. $1<a<3$.
   $$x_{n+1}-1=\frac{(x_{n}-1)(x_{n}+1)}{4},$$ which says that $1<x_n<3$ for all $n$ by induction and
   $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{(x_n-3)(x_n-1)}{4}<0,$$ which says that $\{x_n\}$ decreasing.

Thus, there is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n$ and let this limit equal to $x$.

Thus, $1\leq x<3$ and $x=\frac{1}{4}(x^2+3),$ which gives $x=1$.

3. $a=1$.

In this case $x_n=1$ and our sequence converges.

4. $-3<a<1$.

Here $|x_n+1|\leq|a-1|<4$ for all $n$ and $$|x_{n}-1|=|\frac{(x_{n-1}-1)(x_{n-1}+1)}{4}|\leq|x_{n-1}-1|\cdot|\frac{a-1}{4}|\leq$$
$$\leq|x_{n-2}-1|\cdot|\frac{a-1}{4}|^2\leq|a-1|\cdot|\frac{a-1}{4}|^{n-1},$$
which says that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n=1$ by the limit definition.

5. $a=-3$.

In this case $x_2=3$ and $x_n=3$ for all $n\geq2$, which says that $x$ converges.

6. $a<-3$.

Since $x_{n+1}-3=\frac{(x_n-3)(x_n+3)}{4}>0$ by induction and $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{(x_n-3)(x_n-1)}{4}>0$,

we see that our sequence has no a limit.

Done!